# Algebraic series, rational fraction of two variables in the form of polynomial

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, rational-functions

I come across the following claim:

Let $y\in\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ be an algebraic series, that is, there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$
$A_i(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ for $i=0,...,n$ and $A_n(x)\neq 0$ such that
\begin{equation}A_n(x)y^n+A_{n-1}(x)y^{n-1}+...+A_0(x)=0.\tag{1}\end{equation}

Then for $P(x,z),Q(x,z)\neq0\in\mathbb{C}[x,z]$, $\frac{P(x,y)}{Q(x,y)}$ can be written as a polynomial on $y$ of degree at most $n-1$, with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}(x)$.

I try to expand $1/Q(x,y)$ and then simplify using the relation $(1)$ but as there are infinitely many terms I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: there is no hypothesis on $n$ is minimal or  that $A_0$ non-zero ?

Comment: We may assume that this is the minimal polynomial of $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after discussion with the author of the question (see comments) I
am compelled to rephrase my answer avoiding what is unnecessary
and to bring more detail to the understanding.

as $T^n+p_{n-1}y^{n-1}+...+A_1T+A_0$ is a minimal polynomial of
$y$, then $y^n+...+A_1y+A_0=0$ so $y^n=B_{n-1}y^{n-1}+...+B_0$,
and step by step all polynomial $f(x,y)$ is expressed as
$f(x,y)=C_{n-1}y^{n-1}+...+C_0$, now if $g(x,y)\not=0$ then
$\frac{1}{g(x,y)}$ is algebraic over $K(X)$; let
$P(T)=irre(\frac{1}{g(x,y)},K(X))=T^s+p_{s-}+...+p_1T+p_0$
therefore $p_s(\frac{1}{g(x,y)})^s+...+p_1\frac{1}{g(x,y)}+p_0=0$,
by multiply this equality by $g(x,y)^{(s-1)}$ we get the
expression of $\frac{1}{g(x,y)}$ as a polynomial in $y$ with
coefficient in $K(X)$. finally we conclude that all$f(x,y)$
 and $g(x,y)$ with $g(x,y)\not=0$ we get $\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ as a polynomial in $K(x)[y]$ at most of degree
 $n-1$.

Comment: How do you get $\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}=B_{-m}y^{-m}+...+B_{-1}y^{-1}+B_0+B_1y+...B_ny^{n-1}$?

Comment: by $K(X,Y)=K(X)(Y)$

Comment: Take $f(x,y)=1$ and $g(x,y)=1-y$, what exactly do you have in this case as $B_{-m}y^{-m}+...+B_{-1}y^{-1}+B_0+B_1y+...B_ny^{n-1}$?

Comment: So $\frac{1}{(1-y)}$ is also algebraic over $K(X)$, so let
$P(T)=irre(\frac{1}{(1-y)},K(X))=p_sT^s+...+p_1T+p_0$, therefore
$p_s(\frac{1}{(1-y)})^s+...+p_1\frac{1}{(1-y)}+p_0=0$, by multiply
this equality by $(1-y)^(s-1)$ and dividing by $p_s$ we get the
expression of $\frac{1}{(1-y)}$ as a polynomial in $y$ with
coefficient in $K(X)$. so I think the same argument can use for
any quotient $\frac{1}{g(x,y)}$ because $g(x,y)$ also algebraic.
and very thanks for this important note.